# How to create a smaller (child) div within a div (parent) with Bootstrap 5

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

Using bootstrap5, I wish to create a smaller div, in the bottom right corner of a parent.
Both divs should be responsive, as they contain video.
From the [Bootstrap Utilities Docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/position/), this behavior should be a addressed with

```
<div class="position-relative">
  this is the parent
  <div class="position-absolute bottom-0 end-0">Child</div>
</div>
```

The goal is that the display should resemble a whats-app style of interface, where you have your own video stream in a smaller window, with the other video in the larger (parent) div.

I have tried several options, without success. See [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3za87vpm/4/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Your fiddle doesn't include Bootstrap, you need to include it in the section `Resources` in the left menu.
2. Not sure that I know how WhatsApp is placing its videos, but I guess you want something similar to web conference, like Zoom or MS Teams. If so, here is your fiddle.

https://jsfiddle.net/q84tbroa/

[image]

Comment: Sorry about the missing bootstrap link.. not sure what happened there...
have updated the link, and the above solution works fine for bootstrap 4. 
However, I am seeking a solution for Bootstrap 5.

Comment: @KevinWaterson Doesn't matter, I updated the link to Bootstrap 5 in the answer and as you can see, it works the same way.

Comment: How bizarre.. when I try in a HTML file, I get unexpected results...
https://jsfiddle.net/g6mq54z0/

Comment: @KevinWaterson You added `main` tag that breaks the layout because I didn't add styles for it. https://codepen.io/artemiusgreat/pen/RwpqKeM or fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/d425gjez/1/